# How to write streaming data to Azure data lake from multiple thread?

Tags: azure, apache-flink, azure-data-lake

I am using flink program to write the streaming data which I got from the kafka to Azure Data Lake. When I used synchronisation in getting ADLOutputStream and writing and closing, it works fine but the performance is very poor since only one thread is writing to data lake.When I am using multiple thread without synchronisation it is throwing http 400 illegalargument exception. Is there any way that multiple thread could write to a file in Azure data lake?

Answer (score 2):

Have another think on your design.

One approach would be to write multiple files to the Data Lake - one for each thread. Once in Data Lake, you can use USQL or PolyBase to query over a set of files as if they were one data source. Alternatively, you could then orchestrate a USQL job to merge the files once they are in the lake. This would be local processing and would perform well.

Answer (score 1):

Using AdlOuputStream is not the right mechanism for such parallel writes. AdlOutputStream is designed for a single writer scenario. When ingesting data in parallel from multiple threads there typically are a few characteristics that we commonly observe:

1. You want to optimize for throughput and not do synchronization across threads
2. Ordering (across threads) is typically not important

For specifically addressing these types of scenarios, Azure Data Lake Store provides a unique, high-performance API that we call "Concurrent Appends".

Here is the gist that shows you how to use this API: https://gist.github.com/asikaria/0a806091655c6e963eea59e89fdd40a9

The method is available on the Core class in our SDK: https://azure.github.io/azure-data-lake-store-java/javadoc/com/microsoft/azure/datalake/store/Core.html

Some points to note specific to the Azure Data Lake Store implementation of Concurrent Append:

1. Once a file is used with concurrent appends, you cannot use fixed offset appends with it
2. It is possible that you may see duplicate data in the file. This is possible side effect of error modes and automatic retries.

**Edit:** Also the answer from Murray Foxcraft is suitable for long running threads with reasonable file-rotation policy. The only downside to watch in that approach is that you don't end up with a ton of small files.

Comment: Thanks for the guidance and the gist. I was searching for the answer for the past two weeks.